# Popup window not showing as expected (Android / Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin, modal-dialog, popupwindow, layout-inflater

Good afternoon everyone!

I'm having some problems in a listView popup.

When clicking in any of the list elements, a popup will appear and show all the information of the game (its a TicTacToe history of the plays). I've done the layout for the modal and in the preview is showing as I want.

But when I run in my Android, some elements are "cut" [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZwMh.jpg)...

Current activity code:

```
    private void List_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        View popup = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DesenhoJogo, null); //DesenhoJogo is my Layout for the modal
        PopupWindow janela = new PopupWindow(popup, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, false);
        janela.ShowAsDropDown(popup, Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

        Button voltar = popup.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnVoltar);
        voltar.Click += (s, o) => { janela.Dismiss(); };
    }
```

EDIT:
Layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:orientation="vertical"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    p1:background="@drawable/fundoverde"
    p1:weightSum="3">
    <RelativeLayout
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        p1:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        p1:layout_marginRight="5dp">
        <ImageView
            p1:src="@drawable/xbranco"
            p1:layout_width="35dp"
            p1:layout_height="35dp"
            p1:layout_margin="5dp"
            p1:id="@+id/xJogadorBranco" />
        <ImageView
            p1:src="@drawable/obranco"
            p1:layout_width="35dp"
            p1:layout_height="35dp"
            p1:layout_margin="5dp"
            p1:id="@+id/oJogadorBranco"
            p1:layout_below="@id/xJogadorBranco" />
        <TextView
            p1:text="Jogador 1"
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="35dp"
            p1:layout_toRightOf="@id/xJogadorBranco"
            p1:id="@+id/nomeJogador1"
            p1:layout_margin="5dp"
            p1:gravity="fill"
            p1:textSize="25dp" />
        <TextView
            p1:text="Jogador 2"
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="35dp"
            p1:layout_toRightOf="@id/oJogadorBranco"
            p1:id="@+id/nomeJogador2"
            p1:layout_margin="5dp"
            p1:gravity="fill"
            p1:textSize="25dp"
            p1:layout_below="@id/nomeJogador1" />
        <TextView
            p1:text="Jogadas: "
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="35dp"
            p1:id="@+id/jogadas"
            p1:gravity="center"
            p1:textSize="25dp"
            p1:layout_below="@+id/nomeJogador2"
            p1:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            p1:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            p1:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
        <TextView
            p1:text="Vencedor: "
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="35dp"
            p1:id="@+id/vencedor"
            p1:gravity="center"
            p1:textSize="25dp"
            p1:layout_below="@+id/jogadas"
            p1:padding="5dp"
            p1:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            p1:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            p1:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:orientation="vertical"
        p1:weightSum="3"
        p1:background="@drawable/velha"
        p1:layout_weight="3"
        p1:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        p1:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        p1:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        p1:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        p1:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="0dp"
            p1:layout_weight="1"
            p1:orientation="horizontal"
            p1:weightSum="3"
            p1:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
            <Button xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                p1:id="@+id/pos00"
                p1:layout_width="0dp"
                p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
                p1:layout_weight="1"
                tools:visibility="visible"
                p1:scaleType="centerInside"
                p1:background="@android:color/transparent" />
            <Button xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                p1:id="@+id/pos01"
                p1:layout_width="0dp"
                p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
                p1:layout_weight="1"
                tools:visibility="visible"
                p1:scaleType="centerInside"
                p1:background="@android:color/transparent" />
            <Button xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                p1:id="@+id/pos02"
                p1:layout_width="0dp"
                p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
                p1:layout_weight="1"
                tools:visibility="visible"
                p1:scaleType="centerInside"
                p1:background="@android:color/transparent" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="0dp"
            p1:layout_weight="1"
            p1:orientation="horizontal"
            p1:weightSum="3"
            p1:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
            <Button xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                p1:id="@+id/pos10"
                p1:layout_width="0dp"
                p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
                p1:layout_weight="1"
                tools:visibility="visible"
                p1:scaleType="centerInside"
                p1:background="@android:color/transparent" />
            <Button xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                p1:id="@+id/pos11"
                p1:layout_width="0dp"
                p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
                p1:layout_weight="1"
                tools:visibility="visible"
                p1:scaleType="centerInside"
                p1:background="@android:color/transparent" />
            <Button xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                p1:id="@+id/pos12"
                p1:layout_width="0dp"
                p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
                p1:layout_weight="1"
                tools:visibility="visible"
                p1:scaleType="centerInside"
                p1:background="@android:color/transparent" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="0dp"
            p1:layout_weight="1"
            p1:orientation="horizontal"
            p1:weightSum="3"
            p1:id="@+id/linearLayout4">
            <Button xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                p1:id="@+id/pos20"
                p1:layout_width="0dp"
                p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
                p1:layout_weight="1"
                tools:visibility="visible"
                p1:scaleType="centerInside"
                p1:background="@android:color/transparent" />
            <Button xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                p1:id="@+id/pos21"
                p1:layout_width="0dp"
                p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
                p1:layout_weight="1"
                tools:visibility="visible"
                p1:scaleType="centerInside"
                p1:background="@android:color/transparent" />
            <Button xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                p1:id="@+id/pos22"
                p1:layout_width="0dp"
                p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
                p1:layout_weight="1"
                tools:visibility="visible"
                p1:scaleType="centerInside"
                p1:background="@android:color/transparent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        p1:text="Voltar"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/btnVoltar"
        p1:layout_gravity="bottom"
        p1:textSize="20dp"
        p1:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        p1:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        p1:layout_weight="0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideias how to solve it? 
PS: Started Xamarin two weeks ago, so some coding understendment for me is beeing a little bit hard  =/
Thanks!
 EDIT - SOLUTION:
 I followed jzeferino tips, and researched a bit more. Even after his tips, the layout still wasn't as it should be. So I realized that the problem was with the STATUS BAR height. After changing some minor problems in my layout, all I had to do was create a method to get and return its height

```
public int getStatusBarHeight()
{
    int statusBarHeight = 0;
    int resourceId = Resources.GetIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0)
    {
        statusBarHeight = Resources.GetDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return statusBarHeight;
}
```

In order to use it as a parameter in the following line `janela.ShowAsDropDown(popup, Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, tam);` Where `int tam = getStatusBarHeight();`
And the final result is [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGaDx.jpg)

Comment: You need to post the layout of the modal instead.

Comment: I did... The first image is my layout of the modal

Comment: I was talking about the code.

Comment: Oh, sorry.. =P Updated =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to change up some things.
Try to not use so many fixed dimensions on layout_height and layout_width.
You were using wights incorrect. I removed it.

Final code (note i need to change the name of resources):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/xJogadorBranco"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icno" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/oJogadorBranco"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/xJogadorBranco"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icno" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nomeJogador1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/xJogadorBranco"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:text="Jogador 1"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nomeJogador2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/nomeJogador1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/oJogadorBranco"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:text="Jogador 2"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jogadas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nomeJogador2"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Jogadas: "
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vencedor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/jogadas"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Vencedor: "
            android:textSize="25dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/grid"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/pos00"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                tools:visibility="visible" />

            <Button xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/pos01"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                tools:visibility="visible" />

            <Button xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/pos02"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                tools:visibility="visible" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/pos10"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                tools:visibility="visible" />

            <Button xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/pos11"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                tools:visibility="visible" />

            <Button xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/pos12"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                tools:visibility="visible" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/pos20"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                tools:visibility="visible" />

            <Button xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/pos21"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                tools:visibility="visible" />

            <Button xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/pos22"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                tools:visibility="visible" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnVoltar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="Voltar"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks again for answering. I'll try it now then I post the results here asap

Comment: I used your tips and added a few extra things. Thanks for helping, have a great day!